# Programmatically scan dropbox public folder

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I have a public dropbox folder.  Is there any way to programmatically scan that folder for all files contained within?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropbox has an web API that'll let you do that.  Get one of the [SDKs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/sdk) and go through the tutorials to get started.

Comment: sorry...totally missed this response.  Can it be done without applying to be an Application and doing the whole security token thing?  I don't want to scan other people's public folders, just my own.

Comment: As it stands, you do need to register your application with Dropbox (http://dropbox.com/developers/apps) and you do need to do the OAuth token thing.  However, there is no approval step -- you can start using the API on your own Dropbox account right away.  If you want to allow others to use your program, that's when you need to apply for "production" status.

Answer (score 0):

use it ....

require_once('bootstrap.php');

$metaData = $dropbox->metaData();

foreach($metaData['body']->contents as $file){

```
echo "<pre>";

echo $file->path;
```

}