# List files on site from public dropbox

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm building a site that has a section with a lot of files. The files get updated quarterly. It's a low-traffic site and not a huge amount of data, so rather than have the client send the files to me every quarter, I'd like to host them in a public folder on the client's dropbox. Is there an easy way to do this that wouldn't require any authentication once it was initially set-up? Even better is there a widget I can install? I looked at the dropbox API docs, but those mostly seem to be more complex use cases....

Note: there's not much budget for doing a lot of custom dev, so even though it would be cheaper in the long run to build this, if it isn't fairly drop-in, the client would probably prefer the FTP approach.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically scan dropbox public folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796920/programmatically-scan-dropbox-public-folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Dropbox Core API for the listing: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core